# Preserve variable type in cbind conversion (from list to data.frame) R

Tags: r, dataframe

community. I have the following issue.

Suppose I have the following list.
How can I turn it into a data.frame or data.table without both variables being converted to character type?
I need to keep the original variable type (string and numerical).

```
my_list<-list()
my_list[[1]]<-c("A","B","C")
my_list[[2]]<-c(1,2,3)
do.call(cbind,my_list)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "1" 
[2,] "B"  "2" 
[3,] "C"  "3"
```

Thank you very much!

So, the final outut shoud be:

```
[,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  1 
[2,] "B"  2 
[3,] "C"  3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bind_cols` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

str(bind_cols(my_list))
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ V1: chr  "A" "B" "C"
# $ V2: num  1 2 3
```

Or directly create a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  str = c("A", "B", "C"),
  int = c(1, 2, 3)
)

str(df)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ str: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
# $ int: num  1 2 3
```